# How to keep QR code secure?

Tags: security

As our restaurant management system, customer scan QR code to take order. QR code keeps info of restaurant id and table id. However, how can I make sure that customer scan QR code inside restaurant, not outside restaurant and take useless order maliciously?

Comment: QR Code is a format for sharing links, numbers, etc. So you need to add something like OTP authentication on the link.

Comment: I'm thinking about that. But I'm a little confusing about secure and user experience. Will it make the process more complicated?

Comment: Refer to the security, ease of use and feature triangle. https://cehv7guide.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/ceh1.png

Comment: Yes, that's right. Do you think if I use Location service will solve the problem?